# What can be used to determine the number of active Twitter users

Tags: predictive-models

Say there are 900 million known Twitter accounts in existence.  How would I determine the number of "active accounts", that is, can be expected to tweet in the next 30 days?  Based on the following observation.

I maintain a database of information about Twitter accounts. I'm getting a stream of live tweets from Twitter and recording the account ids of people tweeting. Each account id is only counted once, so if someone tweets twice in one day, that only counts as one id in my database.  It should be noted that this stream is not ALL tweets from Twitter, but a random sample. My database collects 1.3 million unique account ids in the first 24 hrs it is receiving the feed from Twitter.

I would expect at some point in time the number of new unique account ids collected will start to decrease.  By measuring the rate of decrease, can I determine how many accounts are "active accounts" - for instance, after 5 days of collecting this stream, new accounts are now being added to my database at a rate of 0.7 million per 24 hrs, instead of 1.3.

Comment: A bit unclear what you are asking. "new accounts" for example seems to mean "unique data entries collected." Indeed, totally new users confuse the question as well as you only want your denominator to be the 900 million current users. Clean it up, please.

Comment: This is just a variation of the ["Birthday" problem](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/). Instead of people you have tweets, instead of 365 days you have 900 million Twitter accounts.

Comment: @Carl That's an interesting observation.  It seems to me this question has a different focus, although some of the underlying theory is the same.  The Birthday Problem doesn't even formulate the question asked here.

Comment: @whuber I know, it is a variation thereof, not quite the same. I could have said to just work out the permutation/combinations, but wanted to give a bigger structural hint than that.

Comment: @Carl Could you elaborate on what you mean by "structural hint"? The resemblance to the Birthday problem, although real, doesn't seem to advance the solution at all.  This appears to be a difficult question.  One reason is that there is a huge (and unknown) variation among tweeting rates (analogous to huge variation in frequencies of birthdates). More importantly, this question requires analysis of a *stochastic process* in which accounts emerge over time.  Do you see any way in which the analysis of the Birthday problem might provide insight into a solution?

Comment: @whuber Without an organized, simplified  approach any problem is insoluble. I would not solve the problem as a time series. There is no need. What I would do is titrate whole events until 30 days data is achieved and make a first approximation, i.e., a simplification. That is, I would solve the problem for the sequence of discrete events and only then look up occurrence times for that number of events.

Comment: @whuber For example, we can regard the birthday problem as almost intractable. The birthday problem itself usually ignores leap seconds, days and centuries, the slowing of earth's rotation and orbit, the variations in a year's time length caused by variations in the earth's axis of rotation and perturbations of the earth's solar orbit, etc. etc. etc.  What we usually do is ignore problems that do not make much difference to the outcome.

Comment: I don't see how your comment is relevant, Carl.  As has been analyzed elsewhere on this site, small deviations from uniformity of the birthday frequencies are immaterial.  But the present question concerns *huge* deviations, as well as a completely different process (there isn't even an analogous stochastic process in the Birthday problem) and a completely different objective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53353/discussion-between-carl-and-whuber).